# Is this a new Primality Test?

Tags: prime-numbers, integer-lattices, primality-test

Every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is prime if all lattice points on $x+y=n$ are [visible](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/VisiblePoint.html) from the origin.

Graphed points on $x+y=n$ not visible from the origin for potential primes.

[image: 8x8 raster image]

```
// Primality Test
// Every n is prime if all lattice points on x+y=n are visible from the origin.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>


uint64_t gcd(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    return (b != 0) ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}


int isPrimeNumber(uint64_t n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    if (n == 2 || n == 3) return 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) return 0;

    // Start near line x=y.
    uint64_t x = (n / 2) + 2;
    uint64_t y = n - x;
    uint64_t count = sqrt(n) / 2;

    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Check lattice point visibility...
        if (gcd(x, y) != 1) return 0;
        x++; y--;
    }

    return 1;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    uint64_t n = 1000000007;

    if (isPrimeNumber(n) == 1)
    {
        printf("%llu prime.", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%llu not prime.", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't think this through too much yet, but this seems vaguely related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_orchard

Comment: While this is a primality test, from my limited understanding, this isn't faster than the best sieves out right now.

Comment: Re: "However, determining a points visibility is very computationally expensive."  I actually disagree; the gcd computation takes $O(\log n)$ divisions, which is quite fast when $n$ is large.  The main thing slowing you down is the fact that you have to check $\sim n$ lattice points.  That pretty much guarantees that your algorithm will be no faster than checking divisibility by each integer from $2$ to $n-1$ inclusive.

Comment: Seems highly unlikely that such a trivial observation is going to help anyone do anything. How familiar are you with the work that has gone into the most efficient currently known primality tests?

Comment: Extremely hard to imagine that such pattern-based algorithms can compete with the fastest known primality tests. I am not even sure whether this method can at least compete with trial division. Considering Ravi's comment this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: This is another story. Since no comment claimed that the test does not work, I think, it is valid, but I do not understand the test well enough to judge.

Comment: This elementary fact is very old and well-known, and discussed here in the past, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2272536/242)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n=ab$ with $a$ and $b$ greater than $1$ then
$$
n = a + a(b-1)
$$
so $(a, a(b-1))$ is a point on the line.

That says that there are invisible points when $n$ is composite.

Conversely, if $n$ is prime and $n=x+y$ then any common divisor of $x$ and $y$ will divide $n$, so $(x,y)$ is visible.

So this is a valid primality test.

It's not an efficient test.